# Setting value of variable within promise chain in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my web application, there are several components that will need access to the same data (in JSON). To avoid making unnecessary REST calls, I made a module that is supposed make a fetch request and store the result in a variable. On subsequent requests... if the data is available in the module, it will be directly returned (so only one network request is necessary).

For example:

```
var data_module = function(){

  var data; //Module stores the json data in a variable

  return{ //Returns an object that contains a public method accessible to external functions
     get_json:function(){
       if(data){ //If data already exists, then return a Promise object that immediately resolves with data
        return Promise.resolve(data); 
       }
       else{ //Else if data does not exist, make fetch request 
          fetch('/rest/url/endpoint', {credentials:'include'})
          .then(function(response){
              if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
              }
              return response.json(); //Returns json of response
          })
          .then(function(json){
             data = json; //Assigns data the value of json to store the result for subsequent requests
             return Promise.resolve(data) //Returns a Promise that resolves with data

          });


      }
     } //Public method that is supposed to provide access to data

  } 




}(); //Module will automatically execute
```

Outside of the module, I will try to access data like so:

```
some_dom_element.onclick = function(){ //Some html element is clicked and we need the data

   data_module.get_json().then(function(json){
      console.log(json); //However this never gets called 
  });

}
```

It does not work. Even though data_module's get_json function returns a Promise, the .then method does not get called outside of data_module. I was wondering if anyone can explain why this happens? (Or provide a general direction of how to modify the solution to achieve the goal of storing json results of fetch requests).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `else` clause doesn't return anything...

Comment: ^^^ just add `return fetch...`

Comment: but if I return fetch... how do I assign the result of fetch to the data variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the `fetch`

```js
var data_module = (function() {
  var data; //Module stores the json data in a variable

  return { //Returns an object that contains a public method accessible to external functions
    get_json: function() {
      if (data) { //If data already exists, then return a Promise object that immediately resolves with data
        console.log("** From CACHE **")
        return Promise.resolve(data);
      } else { //Else if data does not exist, make fetch request 
      // returning the fetch 
     return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
            credentials: 'include'
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json(); //Returns json of response
          })
          .then(function(json) {
            data = json;
            return Promise.resolve(data) //Returns a Promise that resolves with data

          });


      }
    } //Public method that is supposed to provide access to data

  }
}()); //Module will automatically execute
//Outside of the module, I will try to access data like so:
var some_dom_element = document.getElementById("testBt")
some_dom_element.onclick = function() { //Some html element is clicked and we need the data

  data_module.get_json().then(function(json) {
    console.log(json); //However this never gets called 
  });

}
```

```html
<button id="testBt">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could actually make the code a little shorter by storing the promise that `response.json()` returns and just returning it rather than storing the text and generating a new Promise every time you get it from the cache.

```js
let data_module = (function() {
  let data;

  return {
    get_json: () => {
      if (!data) {
        data = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
          credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            // clear data so next time it tries to contact the server again
            data = undefined;
            throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
          } else {
            // return the promise that .json() returns so it is stored
            // in data
            return response.json();
          }
        });
      }
      
      return data;
    }
  };
}());


data_module.get_json().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
data_module.get_json().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I used `let` and [arrow functions `=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) since any browser that supports `fetch` also supports those.

Comment: This does seem like a better way to do it. I will try it out! Thank you, I am new to javascript and I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are very welcome :) Another thing you might be want to be aware of are [`async` functions](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions), since you are already using `fetch`, all browsers that support it also [support `async` and `await`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions). `async` and `await` can make writing asynchronous code more straightforward, readable and easier to reason about. They have come in real handy in a couple of the projects I've been working on recently.

Comment: For instance, if inside an `async` function, `data_module.get_json().then(data => {console.log(data);});` could be rewritten as `let data = await data_module.get_json(); console.log(data);`

Comment: That looks more readable. I decided to use the approach detailed in your answer instead because it looks more like the singleton pattern. Thanks a bunch! :)